# Why does my table fills with empty objects with just Id?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My movies and customers have many to many relationship. but each time I create a new customer and select movies from dropdown for that customer in form, new customer is made but movie slot comes as empty and then when I check my movies table table in database, new movie would have created with null values apart from new movie id. And my CustomerMovie table(many to many relationship table) will have this new customer Id against new movie id. why by making new customer new movie is made with null values and it doesn't add existing movies to customers.

Additional note, I am not very familiar with Razor @Html tags, so I used just normal For loops and it makes more sense to me at least at the moment.

Here is my customer Model

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
        public int CurrentMembershipTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual MembershipType CurrentMembershipType { get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my movie model

```
    public class Movie
    {
        public Movie()
        {
            this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name must be specified")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my context class:

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{

    public CustomerContext() : base("CustomerContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                    .HasMany<Movie>(s => s.Movies)
                    .WithMany(c => c.Customers)
                    .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("MovieId");
                        cs.ToTable("CustomersMovies");
                    });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
       .HasRequired<MembershipType>(s => s.CurrentMembershipType)
       .WithMany(g => g.Customers)
       .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.CurrentMembershipTypeId);

    }
}
```

this is Customer controller:

```
  public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // private ICustomerRepository iCustomerRepository;
        ICustomerRepository iCustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository(new CustomerContext());
        IMembershipTypeRepository iMembershipTypeRepository = new MembershipTypeRepository(new CustomerContext());
        IMovieRepository imovieRepository = new MovieRepository(new CustomerContext());
        CustomerContext CustomerContext = new CustomerContext();

        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Customer()
        {
            var customers = CustomerContext.Customers.Include(c => c.Movies);
            var Customers = customers.ToList();
            return View(Customers);
        }

        //public ActionResult CustomerForm(Customer Customer)
        public ActionResult CustomerForm(Customer customer)
        {
            var membershipTypes = iMembershipTypeRepository.GetMembershipTypes();
            var Movie = imovieRepository.GetMovies();
            ViewBag.Message = "Customers form is going to display: ";
            CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel
            {
                MembershipTypes = CustomerContext.MembershipTypes,
                Movies = CustomerContext.Movies,
            };
            if (customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter != true)
                ViewBag.Addon = "Selected";
            else
                ViewBag.Addon = "Not Selected";
            return View(customerViewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Customer Customer = new Customer();
            Customer = iCustomerRepository.GetCustomerByID(id);
            CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel
            {
                MembershipTypes = CustomerContext.MembershipTypes,
                Movies = CustomerContext.Movies,
                Customer = Customer
            };
            return View(customer);
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult CustomerForm(int CustomerId, string CustomerName, bool CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter, int membershipTypeId, Movie movie)

        {

            Customer customer = new Customer();
           // Movie Movie = new Movie();

            customer.id = CustomerId;

            customer.Name = CustomerName;

            customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter;
            customer.CurrentMembershipTypeId = membershipTypeId;

            customer.Movies.Add(movie);
            movie.Customers.Add(customer);


            iCustomerRepository.InsertCustomer(customer);
           // imovieRepository.InsertMovie(movie);

            iCustomerRepository.Save();
           // imovieRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Customer");

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int CustomerId, string CustomerName, bool CustomerIsSubscribedToNewsLetter, int membershipTypeId, IList<Movie> movie)
        {
            Customer Customer = new Customer();
            Customer.id = CustomerId;
            Customer.Name = CustomerName;
            Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = CustomerIsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
            Customer.CurrentMembershipTypeId = membershipTypeId;
            Customer.Movies = movie;
            iCustomerRepository.UpdateCustomer(Customer);
            iCustomerRepository.Save();
            //CustomerContext.Movies.AddRange(movie);
            imovieRepository.Save();
            CustomerContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Customer");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer = iCustomerRepository.GetCustomerByID(id);
            iCustomerRepository.DeleteCustomer(customer.id);
            iCustomerRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Customer");
        }

    }
```

This is my Movie controller which only has list all function at the moment:

```
 public class MovieController : Controller
    {
        IMovieRepository iMovieRepository = new MovieRepository(new CustomerContext());
        ICustomerRepository iCustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository(new CustomerContext());
        CustomerContext CustomerContext = new CustomerContext();

        public ActionResult Movie()
        {
            var Movies = iMovieRepository.GetMovies();
            //var movies = CustomerContext.Movies.Include(s => s.Customers);
            return View(Movies);
        }
    }
```

this is customerform View:

```
@model WebApplication2.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel
@*<h4>
    <b>ID:</b> @ViewBag.id <br />
    <b>Name:</b> @ViewBag.Name <br />
    <b>Addon:</b> @ViewBag.Addon <br />
</h4>

<h2>CustomerForm</h2>

<form action="/Customer/CustomerForm" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id:</td>
            <td><input id="CustomerId" type="text" name="CustomerId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input id="CustomerName" type="text" name="CustomerName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsSubscribedToNewLetter:</td>
            <td><input id="CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter" type="text" name="CustomerisSubscribedToNewsLetter" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MembershipType:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="MembershipTypeId" name="MembershipTypeId">
                    @foreach (var membershipType in @Model.MembershipTypes)
                    {
                        <option value=@membershipType.Id>
                            @*@membershipType.SignupFee*@
                            @membershipType.Id
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Movie:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="MovieId" name="MovieId">
                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.MovieId, Model.AllMovies, new { size = 8 })*@
                    @foreach (var movie in Model.Movies)
        {
            <option value=@movie.Id>
                @movie.Name
            </option>
        }
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

below is my customer view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CustomerForm")
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Subscription</th>
        <th>MembershipType signup fee</th>
        <th>Movies</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Name }) |
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })*@
                @*<p><a href="/Customer/Edit/@item.id">Edit Customer</a></p>*@
                <form method="post" action="/Customer/delete/@item.id">

                    <input type="submit" value="delete" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsSubscribedToNewsletter)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentMembershipType.SignupFee)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var movie in item.Movies)
                 {
                    @movie.Name
                 }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Do not use `@foreach` in your view if you want to post the values back to your controller. Use `@for(...)` instead. This way, your inputs get proper indexing

Comment: I tried to it but it would fill the dropdown with Model.Movies[I].Name instead of actual name:   <select id="MovieId" name="MovieId">
                    @for(int i = 0; i < @Model.Movies.Count(); i++)
                    {
                    <option value=Model.Movies[i].Id>
                        Model.Movies[i].Name
                    </option>
                    }
                </select>

Comment: `@Model.Movies[i].Id` with the `@` should do it (same for `Name`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I put @ it underlines red and the error says cant apply indexing with [] to an expression of IEnumerable<Movies>

Comment: I changed to List as @Model.Movies.ToList()[i].Id and same for name, it appears fine and dropdown list looks fine as well, but it still doesn't add movies to customers and same thing as I explained in the original post above